# How could I return a json object with only specific values in python

Tags: python, json

I am new to python coding, but I currently have a Json object that has different values, ex.

`{"term_id":{"url":"http://library.austintexas.gov/taxonomy/term/205"},"name":"Ruiz Branch","address":{"latitude":"30.230228","longitude":"-97.706314"}}`

and I would like to return the json object with only the adress and term_id value.

Comment: What issues are you having [after reading the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say:

```
a = {"term_id":{"url":"http://library.austintexas.gov/taxonomy/term/205"},"name":"Ruiz Branch","address":{"latitude":"30.230228","longitude":"-97.706314"}}

address = a['address']
print(address)
```

> result

```
{"latitude":"30.230228","longitude":"-97.706314"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the element you don't want like this:

```
import json

text = '{"term_id":{"url":"http://library.austintexas.gov/taxonomy/term/205"},"name":"Ruiz Branch","address":{"latitude":"30.230228","longitude":"-97.706314"}}'

json_object = json.loads(text)

del json_object['name']

print(json_object)

{'term_id': {'url': 'http://library.austintexas.gov/taxonomy/term/205'}, 'address': {'latitude': '30.230228', 'longitude': '-97.706314'}}
```

If there are other possible extra elements, you could instead create a new json object to which you add only the elements you want from the original object.